# OWL Carrousel Not Showing Images - WeltPixel Extension

Tags: owl-carousel

I was wondering if anyone can help. I recently installed the **OwlCarrouselSlider** from **WeltPixel** and after **upgrading** to **2.3** the images within sliders for related and upsell products have stopped showing. 
I have checked all the folder permissions and indexers and they look fine. 
Did anyone else had the same issue before or could please come up with any other solution?

[image]

Comment: just reinstall your weltpixel extension

Comment: I did. Cleared all the database tables and didn't work.

Comment: make sure your welt is updated as well

Comment: The problem was related to lazy load settings. Disabling the lazy load option fixed the issue. Thanks all!